# From json elements to xaml xamarin views

Tags: c#, json, xaml, serialization, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do dynamic app via json.Has anyone better idea to convert json elements to xaml views?
I deserialize json file , take type of view and then inicialize view object.

JSON:

```
{
  "User": [
    {
      "type": "Label",
      "name": "lblFullName",
      "fontSize": "20"

    },
    {
      "type": "Entry",
      "placeholder": "UpdatePassword"
    },
    {
      "type": "Button",
      "text": "Update Password"
    },
    {
      "type": "Picker"
    }
  ]
}
```

C#:

```
 viewType = (string)testData["Views"][0]["User"][i]["type"];
           if (viewType=="Label")
            {
                objLabel = new Label
                {
                    Text = "",
                    FontSize = int.Parse(fontSize)
                };

                AccountStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel);
            }
            else if (viewType=="Button")
            {
                Button objButton = new Button
                {
                    Text = viewText
                };
                objButton.Clicked += UpdateButton;
                AccountStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be quite tricky, depends on your needs.

I would start with the **root control**, most probably StackLayout will not cover all the cases and a GridView should be used in some cases. Now StackLayout and GridView should define children views differently.

Some controls should be **combined within a parent control**, as an example Label and Button on the same line. So they should be wrapped within a StackLayout with an orientation set to horizontal.

How your button should respond to user interaction? Where and how you will define the clicked event?

Will you define pages and relations between pages dynamically? 
Without knowing much of your requirement it is hard to propose a solution.

Generally speaking your code will work and maybe will cover simple cases. In case of many nested controls you may suffer from slow performance, so start with optimising your XAML layout first. Define a list of supported controls and improve your JSON deserialization, there are plenty of third party libs to do this, in your case I would take the fastest one, since you heavily depends on deserialization speed.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy . You should use [This](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) Nuget.

With Newtonsoft =>

create the model:

```
public class User{
public float FontSize { set; get; }
public String Name { set; get; }
public Enum Type { set; get; }
public String Placeholder { set; get; }
public String Text { set; get; }
```

}

Consume the model

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(contentResponse);
```

Use the model

```
foreach(User element in users){
if(element.Type == MyEnum.Label){
        //Your logic
    }else if(element.Type = MyEnum.Button){
        //Your logic
    }
```

}

> Note: your contentResponse is a List of Users

Comment: Type should be an enum. FontSize a float. In C# property names should start with an UpperCase letter. If the performance is critical here I would suggest to avoid using Json.NET as it is not the fastest JSON deserializer.

Comment: This is exactly what i have done.However thanks for comment

Comment: @EvZ Thanks for your contributions.